# How to handle the tensor product of fields of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products, transcendence-theory

Let $k$ be a field and let $s$ and $t$ be some transcendental indeterminates.  This question was originally inspired by an exercise asking me to describe the product scheme of $\text{Spec }k(s)$ with $\text{Spec }k(t)$. This obviously comes down to describing the tensor product $k(s) \otimes_{k} k(t)$. Intuitively I would expect this to be $k(s, t)$, but I am aware that this is not the case. I haven't really come across tensor products of this form before, and am running a blank on familiar identities I could use to describe this.

Is anyone able to give me an idea of what this tensor product looks like, or better yet, a commutative algebra resource that actually covers this kind of thing in detail? It seems like most commutative algebra texts stay away from any transcendental extensions, and and field theory books assume it, so I'm not actually able to find it anywhere.

Comment: See Example 6.9 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf.

Comment: @KCd Thank you very much for these notes. They've been very helpful for this problem and some other gaps in my knowledge. I've written up what I hope is a proof of that example in terms of universal properties. If you get a chance, do you think you could glance through and see if it makes sense? I've put it in a separate question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447814/wanting-to-verify-a-proof-about-the-tensor-product-of-transcendental-extensions).

Comment: Where is $\mathbb C$ in the question?

Comment: For future reference, Example 6.9 of Conrad's book has now become Example 7.9.